# How to find the path of properties file dynamically from the code?

Tags: java, properties, quartz-scheduler

I have maven project in Java in which I have a property file (quartz.properties) under this directory:

```
/src/main/resources
```

Now I can use this property file in two ways from this class as shown below:

```
/**
 * Create a StdSchedulerFactory that has been initialized via
 * <code>{@link #initialize(Properties)}</code>.
 *
 * @see #initialize(Properties)
 */
public StdSchedulerFactory(Properties props) throws SchedulerException {
    initialize(props);
}

/**
 * Create a StdSchedulerFactory that has been initialized via
 * <code>{@link #initialize(String)}</code>.
 *
 * @see #initialize(String)
 */
public StdSchedulerFactory(String fileName) throws SchedulerException {
    initialize(fileName);
}
```

I am not sure how can I use `StdSchedulerFactory` class to provide the path of my `quartz.properties` file.

As of now I am providing hardcoded path like this but this is not the right way to provide the path since if anyone else is running this code in their desktop or laptop then it will not work. I will be running this application from my desktop and also I will be making a runnable jar as well so I want that my program should load my properties file dynamically without any hardcoded path.

```
public class TestingQuartz {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws SchedulerException {
        SchedulerFactory factory = new StdSchedulerFactory(
                "C:\\workspace\\tester_quartz\\quartzmain\\src\\main\\resources\\quartz.properties");
        Scheduler scheduler = factory.getScheduler();
        scheduler.start();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As your configuration file is in src/main/resources of a mavenized project, it will be embedded in the resulting artifact (jar, war...) you build with maven. Thus you should load the file "from the classpath" like this :

```
    StdSchedulerFactory factory = new StdSchedulerFactory();
    factory.initialize(this.getClass().getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("quartz.properties"));
```

Comment: `StdSchedulerFactory` doesn't take InputStream as an input.

Comment: Oops yes actually I meant using the initialize(InputStream) method; I changed it in my answer

Comment: I tried using your way - `SchedulerFactory factory = new StdSchedulerFactory();
        factory.initialize(TestingQuartz .class.getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("quartz.properties"));` but somehow it is giving compilation error as `The method initialize(InputStream) is undefined for the type SchedulerFactory`.

Comment: I have updated the code in my question to add more details of how I am using it.

Comment: which version of quartz do you use ? At least 2.2 provides such a method : http://quartz-scheduler.org/api/2.2.0/org/quartz/impl/StdSchedulerFactory.html#initialize(java.io.InputStream)

Comment: I am using 2.2.1 and I do see that method is there in `StdSchedulerFactory()` class but whenever I try to use it the way you told me, I always see compilation error somehow. Problem is `SchedulerFactory` is an interface and I don't see that method over there and may be that's why it is not working for me.

Comment: Mmmh yes the initialize(...) method is declared by StdSchedulerFactory but not in the SchedulerFactory interface. Fixed in my answer

Answer (score 0):

Since it appears to be on your class path you could do this:

```
getClass().getClassLoader().getResource("quartz.properties").toExternalForm()
```

Comment: If the maven project generates a war or ear then deployed on a JavaEE container such as JBoss, it may not work as the URL returned by getResource(...) will refer to a kind of virtual storage area, which won't open properly with File. I suggest using getResourceAsStream in my answer (that arrived a bit later than yours; i'm a slow typer :)

Comment: Thanks - been working a lot in JavaFX for a desktop client and that didn't occur to me...  Good catch.